# Braces in pattern with Cases function

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Here's my problem: I've got a JSON-formatted response and want to match some variables over the response. I'm doing it using `Cases`:

```
JsonResponse := Import["https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?&app_code=djPZyynKsbTjIUDOBcHZ2g&app_id=xWVIueSv6JL0aJ5xqTxb&gen=3&int=true&jsonAttributes=1&languages=it-it&maxresults=9&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=43.605979206920594,13.513478915691394,100", "JSON"]

Points = Cases[JsonResponse, {___ "displayPosition" -> "{latitude" -> lat_,"longitude" -> long_ "}", "navigationPosition" -> "{{latitude" -> _Float, "longitude" -> _Float "}}", "mapView" -> "{bottomRight" -> "{latitude" -> _Float, "longitude" -> _Float "}", "topLeft" -> "{latitude" -> _Float, "longitude" -> _Float "}}", "locationId" -> _String, "locationType" -> "point", "address" -> "{city" -> _String, "label" -> _String, "country" -> _String, "county" -> county_, "state" -> state_, "street" -> st_, "houseNumber" -> num_, postalCode -> zip_ ___} -> {{lat, long} -> {st, num, zip, county, state}}, Infinity]
```

I need to make it consider the inner braces as part of the pattern to be matched (*Mathematica* parses them as meaning list, otherwise).

Comment: It looks like maybe what you want is `Cases[JsonResponse, "distance" -> dist_ :> dist, Infinity]`

Comment: @mfvonh the code strangely returns a void list, i'm gonna show the rest of the code

Comment: I don't see your point trying to do that. The natural way is matching the lists

Comment: @belisarius could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might use [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) to go down the nested rules. At some levels of the data, a list of rules creates an extra set of braces.  The `Flatten /@ First@...` seemed a convenient fix.

```
locations = Flatten /@ First@
    Fold[
     #2 /. #1 &,
     JsonResponse,
     {"response", "view", "result", 
      "location", {"displayPosition", "address"}}];

{{"latitude", "longitude"} -> {"label", "houseNumber", "postalCode", 
    "county", "state"}} /. locations
(*
{{{43.6062, 13.5135} -> {"Via Luigi Paolucci, 8, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "8", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}},
 {{43.6062, 13.5131} -> {"Via Valle Miano, 32, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "32", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}},
 {{43.6061, 13.5141} -> {"Svincolo Miano, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "houseNumber", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}},
 {{43.6065, 13.5132} -> {"Largo Giovanni Bovio, 2, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "2", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}},
 {{43.6062, 13.5128} -> {"Piazzale Bovio Giovanni, 3, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "3", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}},
 {{43.606, 13.5144} -> {"Asse Nord Sud, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "houseNumber", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}},
 {{43.6059, 13.5144} -> {"Asse Nord Sud, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "houseNumber", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}},
 {{43.606, 13.5144} -> {"Asse Nord Sud, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "houseNumber", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}},
 {{43.6062, 13.5144} -> {"Asse Nord Sud, 60125 Ancona AN, Italia", "houseNumber", "60125", "AN", "Marche"}}}
*)
```

**Edit: Addendum**

Note: In some cases `"houseNumber"` is missing. As an alternative to `DeleteCases` mentioned by [LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp), one could relace unreplaced keys by [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html).

```
address = {"label", "houseNumber", "postalCode", "county", "state"};
{{"latitude", "longitude"} -> address} /. locations /. 
 Alternatives @@ address :> Sequence[]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! What if I had to remove the entries without the house number?

Comment: Something like `DeleteCases[{_ -> {_, "houseNumber", __}}]`

Comment: Forgot to ping @Piruzzolo :)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thank you!